# Combining graphs for the same x axis length but when y values have different lengths

Tags: graph, stata, figure

I think this question differs from a few solutions I've seen. I am attempting to stack two graphs together, and the range of the x-axis is the same between graphs. However, for the 2nd graph on the bottom, the values that are in the y-axis are much larger, which shrinks the x-axis.

I was wondering whether anyone knew how to do two different things, each of which involves at a minimum forcing the x-axis to be the same length between graphs:

(a) If the x-axis is equal between graphs, and allowing for the same spacing between the y axis numbers and the y axis label, such that there would be more white space to the left of the y label on the top graph in the combined image;

(b) If the x-axis is equal between graphs, which can push out the y-label in the bottom graph, and asking for there to be enough white space in the top graph between the y label and the y values so that the y labels are aligned with each other.

If anyone can help with these two variations, I would be very grateful. The code is below.

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/wpi1.dta, clear
g wpi10 = wpi * 100 

twoway scatter wpi t, ylabel(, angle(0))
graph save 1, replace

twoway scatter wpi10 t, ylabel(, angle(0))
graph save 2, replace
    
graph combine 1.gph 2.gph, cols(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graph combine` can be a pain to use, so it's better to avoid using it. Try to use `by` instead.

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/wpi1.dta, clear
g wpi10 = wpi * 100 
rename (wpi wpi10) value=
drop ln_wpi
reshape long value, i(t) j(variable) string

twoway scatter value t, ylabel(, angle(0)) by(variable, cols(1) yrescale)
```

Comment: See https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0085 for a riff on this theme. The title: The by() option of graph can work better than graph combine

Comment: Thank you both - I will grant the solution to Wouter. I think I may have presented an overly simple case where each graph follows a similar structure, so I will try working out a case where I use the by option but where both subplots have fairly distinct parts from one another. But I will make a separate post for that (if there are no similar posts). Thanks again!