# Tailoring subplots when using graph by()

Tags: graph, stata, figure

This is in part a continuation of this post ([Combining graphs for the same x axis length but when y values have different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651601/combining-graphs-for-the-same-x-axis-length-but-when-y-values-have-different-len/69651942#69651942)) where I was recommended to use the by() option rather than to use graph combine.

I know when people use by() options, they are hoping to have the plot details developed automatically. But I'm hoping more could be explained for a more specific case - i.e. what if I want slightly different information presented in each? I.e.:

a) What if I want value2 to just be expressed in the top subgraph as well as its legend, but not in the bottom subplot?
b) What if I wanted value2 to be expressed on the y-axis on the right hand side of the top subplot?
c) What if I want to tweak the colors that feature in the top plot and the bottom plot?
d) What if I want to add the letter "A" to the middle of the top subplot and the middle of the bottom subplot?

The (imperfect) code is below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/wpi1.dta, clear
g wpi10 = wpi * 100 
rename (wpi wpi10) value=
drop ln_wpi
reshape long value, i(t) j(variable) string"
g value2 = value - 25
replace value2 = . if variable == "wpi10"

twoway scatter value t, legend(on) ylabel(, angle(0)) by(variable, cols(1) yrescale legend(off))
```

Thanks!

Comment: A paper in press at the _Stata Journal_ discusses some of this territory. but I doubt it will appear for 2-3 months.  Some of these sound difficult. What you can do includes (a) different text in the subtitles, which come from value labels of the `by` variable when defined (b) text that is empty for some groups and populated for other groups as a marker label.  The advice to try the `by()` option doesn't come with a promise that it always get you to where you want to be.